# openpyxl: converting dates to numbers

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've downloaded a xlsx file from Google sheets and because of the locale when people write "4.5" excel interprets it as "the 4th of May".

When reading the file using openpyxl, I recognize the `datetime` python type.

But when I do :

```
cell.value = float(cell.value.day + cell.value.month / 10.0)
```

The type of the cell isn't changed to `float`, Excel still sees it as an `date` as one can see in the following example :

```
>>> import openpyxl as xl
>>> n = xl.Workbook()
>>> s = n.get_active_sheet()
>>> s['A1'] = datetime(2018, 12, 1)
>>> s['A1'].value
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 0)
>>> s['A1'].value = 2.5
>>> s['A1'].value
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 12, 0)
```

How to set value **and** type on a cell ?

EDIT: I was using openpyxl version 2.4 and the behavior described here isn't happening with 2.5 (`s['A1'].value == 2.5`) **but** when adding the line

```
>>> n.save('hello.xlsx')
```

And opening the file with Excel, it still sees it as a date.

Comment: You could give [styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/styles.html#using-builtin-styles) a try and see if that explicitly specifying the style will work..

Comment: In which way would it explain the `cell.value = 2.5`, print(cell.value) # datetime(...) ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem when creating a new workbook using `openpyxl`. A [mcve] will help people assist you in your troubleshooting. You could try setting the style of the cell in question to `'Normal'` (no formatting) and see if the cells then behave correctly.

Comment: I added a testable example to my description, but the error was found by Charlie Clark, it's the `number_format` that must be changed when going from datetime to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel infers date and time types from the number format applied to a number. This is the case in the file you have. Setting the value to 4.5 will not change this, you also need to set the number format to "General".

Comment: Indeed that was it, adding `sheet['I2'].number_format = 'General'` after the `value = 2.5` does the trick, but why wouldn't the `value =` doesn't do that already ? After writing `value = 2.5` I would expect `value == 2.5`

Comment: In the other way around, openpyxl **does** change `number_format` when one write `value = datetime(...)` why not doing so when assigning a `float` ?

Comment: After looking at the bitbucket of openpyxl, I've seen you changed the behavior of cell.data_type recently so that datetime, does it mean this bug won't happen anymore if I update openpyxl to the latest version ? I have 2.4 and the latest is 2.5.

Comment: I tested and now on the latest version, after I did `value = datetime(...)` then `value = 2.5` we have `value == 2.5` but `number_format` is still 'yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss' so when saving to xlsx file, Excel still recognize it as a date.